# Matrix Decompositions: Difference between Cholesky Decomposition, Eigendecomposition and Jordan Normal Form Decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, regression, least-squares, matrix-decomposition

I recently created a [related topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/986805/is-the-square-root-of-an-inverse-matrix-equal-to-the-inverse-of-the-square-root/) about the square root matrix, in case you'd like to refer to that one.

Here's what we want: Consider the matrix $\Omega=E(\mathbf{u}^{\top}\mathbf{u})$, where $\mathbf{u}$ is $n \times 1$, so that $\Omega$ is $n \times n$. Notice $\mathbf{u}^{\top}\mathbf{u}$ is symmetric and positive definite; therefore, $\Omega=E(\mathbf{u}^{\top}\mathbf{u})$ should also be symmetric and positive definite. Since it is symmetric and positive definite, therefore it is invertible, so $\Omega^{-1}$ exists. Moreover, $\Omega^{-1}$ is also symmetric and positive definite.

Next, we use the fact of the symmetry and positive definiteness of $\Omega^{-1}=\left[E(\mathbf{u}^{\top}\mathbf{u})\right]^{-1}$, to decompose it as
\begin{equation}
\Omega^{-1}=\Omega^{-1/2}\Omega^{-1/2}
\end{equation}
where the square root $\Omega^{-1/2}$ is also symmetric, and with the additional property that
\begin{equation}
\Omega^{-1/2}\Omega\Omega^{-1/2}=I
\end{equation}
It was this particular property that inspired my previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/986805/is-the-square-root-of-an-inverse-matrix-equal-to-the-inverse-of-the-square-root/).

My new question is this: what kind of matrix decomposition are we using here? From looking at the [Wikipedia page for matrix decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition), I think it is either

- Cholesky Decomposition
- Eigendecomposition
- Jordan Normal Form Decomposition

which one, however, I am not sure.

By the way: this matrix decomposition into square root matrices is an application used in Generalized Least Squares, and there seems to be a lot of misunderstanding among those using it. The reason I say that is because a quick Google search shows that each author refers to what they're doing here as something different.

Some authors say they're doing Cholesky Decomposition; others talk about eigenvalues. Some authors even decompose $\Omega^{-1}=\Psi\Psi^{\top}$ (with transposes!), which seems quite unnecessary to me, since *I believe* the square root should be symmetric, also. The author I am choosing to follow writes $\Omega^{-1}=\Omega^{-1/2}\Omega^{-1/2}$ (without transposes), and I think this is optimal, since again, I believe $\Omega^{-1/2}$ is symmetric (though I don't know how to prove that).

So, can anyone set this straight? What kind of decomposition are we actually using here for this problem? Thank you for your thoughts!

Comment: Your decomposition, or the equivalent decomposition $\Omega = \Omega^{1/2} I \Omega^{1/2}$ is not a Cholesky decomposition, not an eigendecomposition, nor a Jordan decomposition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This academic uses $\Omega^{-1}=\Omega^{-1/2}\Omega^{-1/2}$ and $\Omega^{-1/2}\Omega\Omega^{-1/2}=I$. I was really hoping to find out what kind of decomposition this is so I could learn more and understand it better.

Comment: Since $\Omega$ is SPD, $\Omega^{-1/2}\Omega\Omega^{-1/2}=I$ is only a congruent transformation. Some authors might use the Cholesky decomposition $\Omega^{-1}=\Psi\Psi^T$ instead of the square root simply because they actually want to compute it (note that the Cholesky decomposition is much easier to obtain than the square root) in their algorithms.

Comment: I think this topic (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/986805/is-the-square-root-of-an-inverse-matrix-equal-to-the-inverse-of-the-square-root/) answers why $\Omega^{-1/2}\Omega\Omega^{-1/2}=I$. However, I'm still not sure what kind of matrix decomposition into square roots this is, or how it works: $\Omega^{-1}=\Omega^{-1/2}\Omega^{-1/2}$

Comment: Omnomnomnom, if not Cholesky, Eigenvalue, or Jordan... what kind of decomposition is $\Omega^{-1}=\Omega^{-1/2}\Omega^{-1/2}$, where I want to make sure that my $\Omega^{-1/2}$'s are symmetric (which is not necessarily the case with Cholesky decomposition, correct?